# How Can I access WCF services using a Web Reference?

Tags: wcf, asmx, wcf-binding

What WCF configuration settings makes WCF service, so that I can access as old ASMX web services? How can I authenticate using Authentication header what I used in Old ASMX web services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use basicHttpBinding

Here is an example of the configuration:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731347.aspx

Comment: but how can I use authentication in basicHttpBinding? Any sample configuration and code?

Comment: Check out the WCF Developer Center on MSDN - tons of samples and stuff! http://msdn.microsoft.com/wcf

Answer (score 2):

Check this out : [ASMX to WCF migration](http://weblogs.manas.com.ar/waj/2007/05/31/asmx-to-wcf-migration/)