# Access WCF by clicking a hyperlink

Tags: c#, wcf, hyperlink

Hi I was wondering if it is possible to access a WCF service by clicking a hyperlink like the following from a browser: https://MyServer/MyWebservice.svc/GetUpdate?id=10

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to publish a Http-mode WCF service, you could refer to the following answer.
[How can I use a WCF Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53200663/how-can-i-use-a-wcf-service/53203436#53203436)
if you want to host the service via HTTPS protocol, you need to add the following configuration and set up a certificate in IIS.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="mybinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer, appreciate it. We have however abandoned the idea here at work using our existing wcf service. Going to setup a rest api, makes more sense for our further requirements.