# How to access any method using http request in wcf serice which is hosted on IIS?

Tags: .net, http, wcf, iis

I have a WCF service application. I want to access this service via http request on web browser.

When I run the WCF service on IISExpress, it works but when I published the service on IIS, returns 404 error. How can I fix this issue?

[image: IIS Express screenshot]

[image: IIS screenshot]

**IService.cs**

```
namespace Protek.WebService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "HelloWorld")]
        [OperationContract]
        string HelloWorld();
    }
}
```

**Service.svc**

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Protek.WebService.Service" CodeBehind="Service.svc.cs" %>
```

**Service.svc.cs**

```
 namespace Protek.WebService
 {
    public class Service : IService
    {
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
 }
```

**Web.config**

```
  <system.serviceModel>

    <behaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DefaultBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"    />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

    </behaviors>
    <services>

      <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="Protek.WebService.Service">
        <endpoint address="ws" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Protek.WebService.IService"/>
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Protek.WebService.IService" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:5858/Service" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>

    </services>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1):

First,stackoverflow is technical Ask-reply forum based on English language, please use English in your description and screenshots.
If you want to publish WCF rest service, please refer to the following reply.
[How can I use a WCF Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53200663/how-can-i-use-a-wcf-service/53203436#53203436)
Moreover, when we host the WCF service in IIS, the base address is provided by IIS, there is no need to add base address to your configuration file.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d42fc165-052d-476a-9580-1240b3d0293d/specify-endpoint-in-wcf-webconfig?forum=wcf
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue via I added this line to my service Web.config file. My http error was 404.3

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
       <add
          name="svc-Integrated"
          path="*.svc"
          verb="*"
          type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
     </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Are your tried to Enable Http Activation in windows features? which located in Control-Panel-Program and Features-turn windows features on or off-netframework advanced services-wcf service-http activation.